# Is it a bad idea to use object type(Long) as a parameter type?

Tags: java, exception

Say, the function setX is defined as follows:

```
public void setX(Long l) {
   .....
   .....
}
```

If the function is called with null value in parameter, then what would happen? Will it caused NPE exception if we are doing auto unboxing somewhere in the function?

Can we say safely as a practice thats its a bad practice to use Long as the parameter to a function and instead one should always use the long?

Comment: It's best to make passing `null` impossible (by using `long`), second best to throw an exception if `null` is passed, and very bad to have the program do undetected nonsense in the `null` case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you auto-unbox the `Long` into `long` without checking for null, you will get `NullPointerException`.

Using a `Long` instead of `long` makes sense if your method handles `null` values passed to it. If you never intend to pass `null`, you should use `long`.

And if you are using Java 8 or higher, you can also use `OptionalLong`.

If your method is a setter (i.e. sets the value of some instance variable), as implied by the `setX` name, it would only make sense for the argument to a `Long` if the corresponding instance variable is also `Long` (assuming it is allowed to be `null`).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not bad idea!

- Do use `long` when your method does not accept `null`.
- Do use `Long` when your method accepts and correctly works with `null`.

I personally try to avoid null-checks, therefore I use `long` whenever I can.

```
public void setX(Long l) {}
public void setY(long l) {}
```

client:

```
setX(1L); // OK - use long as parameter's value -> autoboxing to Long
setX(new Long(1L));  // OK - use Long as parameter's value
setX(null);  // OK - use null as parameter's value -> Long is Object and null is correct value

setY(1L); // OK - use long as parameter's value
setX(new Long(1L));  // OK - use Long as parameter's value -> autounboxing to long
setX(null);  // Compile time error - use null as parameter's value -> long is not an Object and null is not correct value
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are asking this question implies that you don't have a specific need to pass a `null`.  (Because if you *did* need to pass it, then `long` is simply not applicable!)

So, assuming that you don't need to pass `null`, `long` is preferable to `Long` for the following reasons:

1. With `Long` there is always the possibility of a NPE if a `null` is passed unexpectedly.  And if you test for `null` to avoid the NPE, and find a `null` ... what do you do then?  (Answer: probably you shouldn't test!)
2. Boxing and unboxing a `Long` has small runtime overheads compared with passing and using a `long`.
3. `Long` consumes more heap space than `long` in most cases.

---